# Tablet with very long boot time, what can I try?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, boot

I apologize if this question is too open-ended, but I wanted to collect different ideas regardless of the specific tablet model.

I've owned an Android 4.1 tablet for quite some time now. When I first got it, the boot time was very quick. Lately, however, it takes much longer to boot. The lengthened time is **not** spent during the boot-animation, it's spent on the splash screen that appears before the animation.

I have rooted this tablet and am willing to pry deeply into the system files to try and resolve the problem.

What steps can I try?

Comment: How about taking a logcat during boot. May throw up some hints?

Comment: @beeshyams Not sure if logcat is running at the point that it is slow. However I will give it a try.